# Autofac equivalent of this specific Ninject binding

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, ninject, autofac

In Ninject I have:

```
 kernel.Bind<IDomainEventHandler<WinnerSelectedEvent>>()
        .To<WinnerSelectedHandler>();
```

What is the Autofac equivalent of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Autofac equivalent of Ninject's:

```
kernel.Bind<Type>().To<Impl>();
```

Is:

```
builder.RegisterType<Impl>().As<Type>();
```

So the equivalent should be simply:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<WinnerSelectedHandler>().As<IDomainEventHandler<WinnerSelectedEvent>>();
var container = builder.Build();
```